# Google Sheets - Stopping ARRAYFORMULA messing up columns while sorting results with a total included

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

I have this pretty straightforward formula in my [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vMbnxv-Oz5hzEowZvjrc1KVWwI1q0N03cs-z9Zs5lBE/edit#gid=0):

> ={"Number of purchases"; SUM(C3:C) ; ARRAYFORMULA(if(isblank(A3:A),,sumif('Raw Data'!A:A,A3:A,'Raw
> Data'!B:B)+sumif('Raw Data'!A:A,B3:B,'Raw Data'!B:B)))}

The issue is when I apply a filter to row 1, my SUM will be messed up if I sort the data.
I would like my filter to remain in row 1 and not to row 2.

Any solution/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why must the filter in Row1? If you just put the sum in row 1, seperate it from the arrayformula instead, and everything else start from row2, than the issue won't exists.

Comment: @Ping Yes that would actually solve my issue. But in term of layout it's really "weird" to have the total above your column header isn't it? Especially since I have a lot of columns that include sums in my original spreadsheet.

Comment: well, in term of layout, it is also not less "weird" to place the total in row 2 than in row 1...
shouldn't total be placed somewhere at the bottom of the data set normally?

Comment: @Damien try to change filter range from row 2 (see copied sheet)

Comment: @Ping Agree, but when you have more than 30 rows, then it makes sense to have it at the top for visibility purposes

Comment: @Terio, thanks for that. This is actually my current situation, having the filter being placed on the total row (row 2) instead of the column header (row1). Would it be possible to use an additional function like OFFSET to exclude the total from the filtering system?

Comment: when it makes sense to have the total at the top for visibility, it do also makes sense to me to have the total at row1, for simplify things and get to job done maybe? I can't think of any way you can do this with the build-in filter in google sheet.

Comment: @Ping Alright. i work for agency so some clients can be annoying when it comes to layout and design. That's why these kind of problems that usually look superficial (for me included) can be an issue with some demanding clients. But If it's not possible I will either keep the filter in row 2 (total) or swap the total and header like you suggested. Thanks for your help anyways !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can do is remove Column C, and stop the formula from breaking when you sort Column B.

Can't think of any way that could stop row2 being sort if you must use the build-in filter of google sheet in row1.

[image]

[image]

At lease if the filter is allowed to be set like this in column 2, this could work.

[image]

Comment: To help with this answer, this is the code in text so it is easier to copy: ```={"Number of purchases";
LAMBDA (PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2, PRODUCTS, ITEMS,
  BYROW({PRODUCT1, PRODUCT2}, LAMBDA (ROW,
   IF (INDEX (ROW, 2)="SUM:",
    SUM(ITEMS),
    SUM(FILTER(ITEMS, PRODUCTS=INDEX(ROW,1)))+SUM(FILTER(ITEMS, PRODUCTS=INDEX(ROW, 2)))
   )
  ))
 ) ($A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8, 'Raw Data'!$A:$A, 'Raw Data'!$B:$B)}```

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially reconfigure your formulas such that rather than spilling the SUM into row 2 using an array literal as you are currently doing, instead you include the SUM into row 1 but place the sum below the Header using a carriage return character:

```
={"Number of purchases"&CHAR(10)&SUM(C2:C);...}
```

N.B. 1 - as row 2 would no longer be required for the SUM you can move all of your formulas up one row to run from row 2 instead, so the SUM would be calculated from C2:C instead in this case, as I have shown.

N.B. 2 -  If you want to spill results out of the header cell of a column as you have been doing, AND have some sort of aggregation of the results in THAT column also in the header, you can't just SUM the range of cells below the header as due to order-of-operations the SUM gets generated before the other cells get filled in (so will always = 0...) - you need to calculate the sum in-line using the same array expression as used to spill the cells, i.e.:

```
={"Header"&CHAR(10)&SUM(array_expression);array_expression}
```

For a long/complex array_expression, consider using a LAMBDA so you don't have to explicitly repeat the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very insightful. I added your solution in the original spreadsheet.

Comment: No problem - glad to help. Please mark the answer as accepted if you consider that it has answered your question.